# PostgreSQL search using like does not return right value

Tags: sql, postgresql, pg-trgm

I am using `pg_trgm` in my name column as :

```
    create index if not exists idx_gin_iperson_name on iperson using gin (name gin_trgm_ops)
```

in `iperson` table, I have a column with name `Jose Goruir` and in query:

```
SELECT * FROM iperson p where ((name ilike unaccent('%Jos%'))) limit 3000;
```

the result is okay, I mean it will return `Jose Goruir` but with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM iperson p where ((name ilike unaccent('%Jose%'))) limit 3000;
```

it won't return  `Jose Goruir`. any idea?

Comment: Don't you need to unaccent the name rather than the LIKE string?

Comment: @martinclayton I need both, I think

Comment: Your question seems to be about accents, but you don't show any accents.  Which means we don't know what you are really trying to ask.  SO does support accented characters.

Comment: Do you think the accent is the problem? @jjanes

Comment: Yes.  I can't reproduce the problem without accents.  '%Jose%' pulls out 'Jose Goruir' fine

Comment: you are right, I think we need two accents for field too. @jjanes